# Defining a \newcommand does not work

Tags: macros, acronyms

I am trying to define a new shorter command for acronym like this:

```
\newcommand{\acB}[3]{%
    \newacro{#1}[#2]{#3}%
}
```

But latex struggles with `[` and `]` around `#2`. How do I escape these quotes so that this compiles?

Comment: that definition does not generate an error, if you get an error  please provide a _complete_ small test document that people can run to see the error and test answers.

Comment: Works for me. You must use of course `\acB{}{}{}` (braces three times). Or you could just do `\let\acB=\newacro`, but I really don't see the point...

Comment: @campa Shit! I was using `\acB{}[]{}`! :/// Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments and is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @schandard I agree.